¿En qué países se usa "menos" para decir la hora?
Por ejemplo: 3:45 "Son las cuatro menos quince." Yo soy de México y personalmente no conozco a nadie que use menos. Me gustaría saber en qué países las personas usan menos porque así es como ellos lo usan cuando hablan.  No me interesa saber cómo lo enseñan los libros. Me interesa saber cómo lo usa la gente comúnmente. Gracias por sus opiniones.

La verdad es que no puedo hablar todo mi país, España. Yo personalmente empleo las dos formas indistintamente.

En España se usa, definitivamente. Quizá ahora menos, debido a los relojes digitales, pero para los que aún un reloj es esa cosa redonda con dos agujas, seguro que no dicen "las cuatro menos quince",  pero sí "las cuatro menos cuarto" de la forma más natural, Y seguro que en México también. Pregúntele a los viejitos.

En la Argentina decimos ‘son las cuatro menos cuarto’, lo de cuarto solo por ser justo :45. Si fuera 3:50, diríamos ‘cuatro menos diez’, si fuera 3:35 diríamos ‘cuatro menos veinticinco’. Es decir, cambiamos a ‘menos .’ a partir de :31 hasta :59. Irregularidades marcadas en negrita:

:00 -> en punto
:05 -> y cinco
:10 -> y diez
:15 -> y cuarto
:20 -> y veinte
:25 -> y veinticinco
:30 -> y media
:35 -> menos veinticinco
...
:45 -> menos cuarto
...

Aunque usemos en lo escrito el formato de 24 horas, seguiríamos diciendo ‘son las cuatro menos cuarto’ indistintamente de si el reloj marca 3:45 o 15:45.
Por lo que estuve averiguando, esto también aplicaría para Uruguay, Chile y gran parte de España. En el resto del mundo dirían cosas como ‘tres y cuarenta y cinco’ (quince y cuarenta y cinco para el formato de 24 horas) o ‘un cuarto para las cuatro’. En mi opinión, la primera expresión es excesivamente formal, que solo quedaría bien al leer actas o documentos importantes pero en tal caso generalmente diríamos algo como ‘quince horas y cuarenta y cinco minutos del día ...’. Y la otra expresión parece calcada del inglés. Quizá porque estamos lejos del hemisferio norte no nos hemos dejado contaminar con tanto gringuerío, pero en definitiva lo cierto es que cada quién lo puede decir como prefiera.
En este hilo de Duolingo hay un debate filosófico al respecto de cómo debería decirse la hora.
